# Is it correct to say that since the derivative of a function is zero at a certain point imply that this point is an inflection point?

Tags: calculus, functions

I would like to know if it is correct to say that if a polynomial function P has its derivative that is equal to zero at one point then:

- There is only one *inflection point* thus the function has at most two real roots.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to say that since the derivative of a function is zero at a certain point imply that this point is an inflection point?

No, because at inflection point curve changes from concave to convex and the second derivative must be zero[actually not always], consider as a counterexample $x^2$,(it's a polynomial too) it has $0$ as a point of zero derivative but even though the curve is concave as a whole.

> There is only one inflection point thus the function has at most two real roots.

No, consider $x^3-6x^2+11x-6$ which has $2$ has a point of inflection and $1.5,2.5$ as points of zero derivative but even though it has more than two real roots, three, viz. $1,2,3$.

Comment: so then how would you justify that it has at most two real roots?

Comment: "justify that it has"; it=?

Comment: a polynomial of degree 4 with only one solution to P'(x)=0

Comment: @JerryTaylor use Rolle's theorem.if it has more than two roots, ther must me more than one points of zero derivatives